# Samsung hovering API with finger

Tags: android, api, hover, galaxy, samsung-mobile

Samsung has done something great with the hovering API, and I'm interested in including it in my app. The problem is that the hovering API included in the [SPen SDK](https://developer.samsung.com/dev/sPenMainList.do) only work with the SPen and not with the finger detection like the latest apps do on the Samsung Galaxy S4.

Can anyone provide me with a link to the right SDK or even a sample project?

EDIT: Nifhel commented, fallow this link: [Floating Touch on Galaxy S4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666965/floating-touch-on-galaxy-s4) (**requires API 12** and to create a new class that inherit from `TextView` for instance)

EDIT: The accepted answer is a better solution and works perfectly well (**requires API 14** but easier to use).

Comment: Did you managed to find a way to detect the finger?

Comment: No, I'm still looking for something or waiting for Samsung to communicate about this API.

Comment: I posted the solution here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666965/floating-touch-on-galaxy-s4

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've tried out the method described on the link recommended by Nifhel.
The only thing you have to do is adding a new intent filter for your Activity in the manifest, no need to override "dispatchGenericMotionEvent":

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.sec.android.airview.HOVER" />
</intent-filter>
```

After that you have to add an onHoverListener to you View and it will work fine.
For example in my ListAdapter:

```
convertView.setOnHoverListener(new OnHoverListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("ListAdapter", "Hover: " + item);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi. This solution works well if you're not starting activity in new process. Do you know how to enable floating touch when activity started in new process?

Answer (score -1):

Based on what I could [find](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/how-to-enable-finger-hover-detection/78/230762?boardName=SPenSDK&startId=zzzzz~), Samsung is yet to release an API that supports finger hovering (AirView).

Answer (score -4):

Try ApiDemos in latest version of sdk android-17 (4.2.2) -> Views -> Hover.class. It can give you a heads up on Hover event.

Comment: This Demo demonstrates how to use onHover listener, which works for a mouse or touchpad. Not even close to what I'm looking for.