# Floating Touch on Galaxy S4

Tags: android, hover, galaxy, samsung-mobile

Samsung Galaxy S4 have the "*Floating Touch*" functionality, in which the finger can be detected even if the screen is not touched.

I would like to fire an event on a button (`btn1`) when the finger is passing hover it.

I tried using the `OnHoverListener`, but `onHover` never get called when the `MotionEvent` is `MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER` or `MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT` or `MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE`, which are the event that I need.

This is my code:

```
btn1.setOnHoverListener(new OnHoverListener() {
@Override
public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("FloatingTouch", "onHover: "+event.getAction());
    switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
          Log.d("FloatingTouch", "ACTION_HOVER_ENTER" );
          return true;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:
          Log.d("FloatingTouch", "ACTION_HOVER_MOVE" );
          return true;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
          Log.d("FloatingTouch", "ACTION_HOVER_EXIT" );
          break;
      default:
          break;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Do I miss something? Maybe some permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I finally got it!

To make it work you have to:

1. Add a new intent filter to `com.sec.android.airview.HOVER` for your Activity in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.sec.android.airview.HOVER" />
</intent-filter>
```

2. Add an `onHoverListener` to you `View`

```
convertView.setOnHoverListener(new OnHoverListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("ListAdapter", "Hover: " + item);
        return false;
    }
});
```

It will work.

Comment: Where should I put the intent filter in the manifest? If I put this line in the intent-filter of the main activity, then Eclipse installs the app on my phone but it says that there is no launcher activity.
If I don't include this line, it also works. Really great !

Comment: Hmm, ok. If you don't put that line on th emanifest, you won't get any event (it's odd that for the main activity it still works).