# Possible to Get As3 Finger Hover Events (on Galaxy S4)?

Tags: actionscript-3, galaxy

I just saw a commercial for a galaxy s4 and there was a video of the screen changing dynamically and responding to a finger hovering above it but not at all touching it. I am an as3 developer. I was wondering if it is possible to get hover events or if native android s4 can even listen for it.

Answer (score 1):

AS3 has no built in support for this.

Android [can do it natively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666965/floating-touch-on-galaxy-s4), but this uses event handlers on the active view. However, I'm not sure if the root View instance that Air is using is exposed to ANEs.