# How can I get finger hovering position (x,y) in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to write an Android App (using Android Studio) that uses the hover capabilities of my Galaxy s5 as a cursor. Currently I have an overlay cursor that can appear at different positions on screen but I need to get the (x,y) values of the finger position hovering above. It seems to be related to Motion Events but I am a beginner in Android coding so I really need help. Just to clarify getting the touch position is not enough I need the hovering position.

Thank you in advance;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Touch position in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476779/how-to-get-the-touch-position-in-android)

Comment: Refer to the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666965/floating-touch-on-galaxy-s4